# GUI - getting something on next line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I have created a GUI, and am using the `FlowLayout`.

I have 2 labels and a button, that are on the same line, however I want the button on a separate line to the 2 labels.  Is there any way of going about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways, most of which involve making a nested layout (putting one layout inside another).  Here is an example.

[image: Button/Label Layout]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class ButtonLabelLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Border Layout"));

                JPanel labels = new JPanel();
                labels.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Flow Layout"));
                labels.add(new JLabel("Label 1"));
                labels.add(new JLabel("Label 2"));

                gui.add(labels, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                gui.add(new JButton("Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

For a more comprehensive example of nesting layouts, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271).

[image]

Comment: the fan of nested panels :-) Can be done, but breaks down if cross-panel alignment is needed. Plus, fragments conceptually related "view" into bits dictated by implementation concerns. If there is a choice, don't - instead, group views by semantics and reach layout goals by _one_ decent LayoutManager

Comment: @kleopatra I considered using `GroupLayout` ( for an SSCCE, it's gotta' be J2SE ;), but that was more LOC.

Comment: to consider GroupLayout you have to be tougher even than the GridBag bunch <g> (So I was told, never wasted my time with any of advertized 'powerful' core managers, there are options out in the wild which give you all you need with considerably less effort)

Comment: @kleopatra I've used `GroupLayout` once or twice to good effect.  It's worth having a look at (if you get bored with all your 3rd party layouts with chocolate sprinkles).